# "Error de compilación: la variable no ha sido definida" usando la función "call"

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Tengo una macro que abre una página web, asigna ciertas variables, y luego llama a otro procedimiento utilizando la función `call`. Necesitaría utilizar algunas de las variables definidas en el primer procedimiento (como por ejemplo, `numberOfPages`) en el segundo procedimiento pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> Error de compilación: la variable no ha sido definida.

### ¿Alguien sabe como hacer para solucionarlo? Detallo más abajo el procedimiento. Muchas gracias!

```
 Sub test()

 Dim element As IHTMLElement

 Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection

 Dim ie As InternetExplorer

 Dim numberOfPages As Double

 Dim html As HTMLDocument

 Set ie = New InternetExplorer

 ie.Visible = True

 ie.navigate "https://cebra.com.ar/category/73/Juego-de-Construccion.html"

 Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

 Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page …"

 DoEvents

 Loop

 Set html = ie.document

 Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("container")

 Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

 numberOfPages = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".setPage").Length

 'MsgBox numberOfPages

     For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("li")

          For Each element In elements

               If element.className = "container" Then

               'Do something

               Call procedure

               End If

          Next element

     Next

 MsgBox "Done"

 End Sub

----------------------------------------
 Option Explicit

 Public Sub procedure()

 MsgBox numberOfPages

 'Aquí es donde quiero utilizar la ventana de internet explorer abierta y algunas variables definidas en el procedimiento anterior

 End Sub
```

Comment: hace uno minutos publicaste esta Pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/269125/107347 estan relacionadas?

Comment: Hola Orlando, si, están relacionadas. Es todo parte de un mismo procedimiento pero para simplificar y no marear lo he dividido en dos partes. Gracias!

Comment: Así como estan son casi iguales o muy parecidas lo cual te la podrian marcar como duplicada.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas declarando la variable numofpages dentro del sub "test"
,de esa forma la variable solo se puede utilizar dentro de "test" y cuando la llamas desde otro sub no es reconocida

Puedes probar de la siguiente manera?

```
 Dim numberOfPages As Double 'Lo ponemos fuera del sub "test"

 Sub test()

 Dim element As IHTMLElement

 Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection

 Dim ie As InternetExplorer

 ' esto lo comentamos pq ya lo hemos declarado al principio    ' Dim numberOfPages As Double
```